# LDAP - PAM Home Directory Incorrect

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have OpenLDAP setup on Centos 6. LDAP has my account homeDirectory as /home/me but a server that I'm logging into is trying to create my home directory at /users/me.

**How can I trace down why the home directory is getting set incorrectly?**

Comment: What's the output for `ldapsearch -x uid=youruser`? (include any necessary additional parameters, such as `-D`, `-W`, `-h`, `-b`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 6 ldap posix attributes may be fetched by nss-pam-ldapd or by sssd, and both modules are able to perform attribute remapping, modifying or ignoring information returned by the ldap server.

First check the `passwd` map in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, if it says `ldap` then check for attribute mapping in `/etc/nslcd.conf`, if it says `sss` then check for attribute mapping in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`